# Why has it become common to say a drasha in a mourner's home?

Tags: torah-study, mourning-aveilus, masechet-moed-katan

If I understand the top of [Mo'ed Kattan 23a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=23&format=pdf) correctly, it says that one should not say *aggadah* in a mourner's home. (The phrasing immediately after says that they did this after Rav Chananiah ben Gamliel's death. However, I understand that this was an exception and not another opinion that everyone may do so.)

I have seen in almost every moruner's home during shiva that the rav or someone else recites a mishnah or some other halacha between mincha & Ma'aric in teh mourner's home. If it is, in fact, halacha that one may not recite Aggadah (I assume Divrei Torah is the same idea) in a mourner's home, how are they allowed to do this?

Comment: Are you assuming the mourner isn't there at the moment? Or are they careful to only discuss sad Halakhot? (A mourner is strictly prohibited from learning regular/happy Torah during Shiva, as on Tisha bAv.)

Comment: @DoubleAA The mourner is almost always in the room at that time, from what I have seen. I have seen 1 or 2 occasions when the rav discussed halachot that are "neutral" such as hilchot *chametz* (as Pesach was approaching, then.)

Comment: a mourner is completely forbidden from learning about chametz during shiva, just like a regular Jew on Tisha bav

Comment: @DoubleAA So, essentially, the Gemara allows only "sad" topic in the mourner's home? If this is so, how do we learn this from the Gemara, or how is that deduced?

Comment: The Gemara says explicitly a mourner is forbidden to learn Torah on Moed Katan 21a. Again this is just like on Tisha bAv. I'm not sure why you're confused. I haven't said anything about what is permitted in a mourner's home, only what a mourner can learn.